# How to switch to lightning in mobile browser chrome

Tags: lightning, mobile, classic

When I use Chrome on my laptop I use Lighting and I have no problem. When I use the Salesforce App I have no problem.

But when I use the Salesforce on my mobile device(via browser Chrome), I get Classic version. I do not have the possibility to switch back to Lightning from my mobile phone.

How to switch to Lightning interface on my mobile device?

Comment: Maybe `show desktop site` checkbox can make easy for you in the browser options.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working :-)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Worth adding your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are accessing it from mobile to see in the desktop mode you can ask chrome to force desktop version of website. There is a checkbox which can do all the magic.

[image]